# How to have getcwd() give path with ~ in place of home folder?

Tags: vimrc, statusline, working-directory

I have the following (simplified) statusline config in my `vimrc`:

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=%{getcwd()}
```

When I'm somewhere in my home directory on macOS, my statusline looks like this:

```
/Users/ruohola/dotfiles/vim
```

But I would want it to just show it like this:

```
~/dotfiles/vim
```

And when I would be somewhere in the root directory the path should just be shown normally e.g:

```
/Libarary/Application Support
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
substitute(getcwd(),$HOME,'~','')
```

Comment: When I try: `set statusline+=%{substitute(getcwd(),$HOME,'~')}` I get the error: `E119: Not enough arguments for function: substitute`.

Comment: I think there’s a flags argument. I put a blank string in but check the help

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!